# tac_plus Active Directory config

Tags: active-directory

I seem to be having an issue with the pro bono tac_plus configuration.

my switch is giving me the following log message

May  4 20:58:52 sv5-c1-r104-ae02 Aaa: %AAA-4-EXEC_AUTHZ_FAILED: User jdambly failed authorization to start a shell

if I look at the tac_plus logs it looks like my group mapping is not configured correctly, here is the log

```
May  4 14:04:22 neteng tac_plus[14476]: 1/9a920270: Start authorization request
May  4 14:04:22 neteng tac_plus[14476]: 1/9a920270: cfg_get: checking user/group jdambly, tag (NULL)
May  4 14:04:22 neteng tac_plus[14476]: 1/9a920270: cfg_get: checking user/group jdambly, tag (NULL)
May  4 14:04:22 neteng tac_plus[14476]: 1/9a920270: user 'jdambly' found
May  4 14:04:22 neteng tac_plus[14476]: 1/9a920270: cfg_get: checking user/group jdambly, tag (NULL)
May  4 14:04:22 neteng tac_plus[14476]: 1/9a920270: jdambly@192.168.0.19: not found: svcname=shell@world protocol=
May  4 14:04:22 neteng tac_plus[14476]: 1/9a920270: jdambly@192.168.0.19: not found: svcname=shell protocol=
May  4 14:04:22 neteng tac_plus[14476]: 1/9a920270: jdambly@192.168.0.19: svcname=shell protocol= not found, default is <unknown>
May  4 14:04:22 neteng tac_plus[14476]: 1/9a920270: Writing AUTHOR/FAIL size=18
```

here is my config

id = tac_plus {
        debug = PACKET AUTHEN AUTHOR MAVIS

```
    access log = /var/log/tac_plus/access.log
    accounting log = /var/log/tac_plus/acct.log
    authorization log = /var/log/tac_plus/auth.log

    mavis module = external {
            setenv LDAP_SERVER_TYPE = "microsoft"
            #setenv LDAP_HOSTS = "ldaps://xxxxxx:3268"
            setenv LDAP_HOSTS = "xxxxxx:3268"
            setenv LDAP_SCOPE = sub
            setenv LDAP_BASE = "dc=nskope,dc=net"
            setenv LDAP_FILTER = "(&(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))"
            setenv LDAP_USER = "xxxx@nskope.net"
            setenv LDAP_PASSWD = "xxxxxxxx"
            #setenv AD_GROUP_PREFIX = devops
            # setenv REQUIRE_AD_GROUP_PREFIX = 1
            # setenv USE_TLS = 0
            exec = /usr/local/lib/mavis/mavis_tacplus_ldap.pl
    }

    user backend = mavis
    login backend = mavis
    pap backend = mavis
    skip missing groups = yes
    host = world {
            address = 0.0.0/0
            prompt = "Welcome\n"
            key = cisco
    }

    group = devops {
            default service = permit
            service = shell {
                    default command = permit
                    default attribute = permit
                    set priv-lvl = 15
            }
    }
```

}

I'm trying to map the ad group devops to the group in the config but I think that's failing and I don't get why

Answer (score 1):

so LONG story short I got this working using the following config.

```
#!../../../sbin/tac_plus

id = spawnd {
    listen = { port = 49 }
    spawn = {
            instances min = 1
            instances max = 10
    }
    background = no
}

id = tac_plus {
    debug = PACKET AUTHEN AUTHOR MAVIS

    access log = /var/log/tac_plus/access.log
    accounting log = /var/log/tac_plus/acct.log
    authorization log = /var/log/tac_plus/auth.log

    mavis module = external {
            setenv LDAP_SERVER_TYPE = "microsoft"
            #setenv LDAP_HOSTS = "ldaps://xxxxxxxxx:3268"
            setenv LDAP_HOSTS = "xxxxxxxxx:3268"
            #setenv LDAP_SCOPE = sub
            setenv LDAP_BASE = "cn=Users,dc=nskope,dc=net"
            setenv LDAP_FILTER = "(&(objectclass=user)(sAMAccountName=%s))"
            setenv LDAP_USER = "xxxxxxxx"
            setenv LDAP_PASSWD = "xxxxxxxx"
            #setenv FLAG_FALLTHROUGH=1
            setenv UNLIMIT_AD_GROUP_MEMBERSHIP = "1"
            #setenv EXPAND_AD_GROUP_MEMBERSHIP=1
            #setenv FLAG_USE_MEMBEROF = 1
            setenv AD_GROUP_PREFIX = ""
            # setenv REQUIRE_AD_GROUP_PREFIX = 1
            # setenv USE_TLS = 0
            exec = /usr/local/lib/mavis/mavis_tacplus_ldap.pl
    }

    user backend = mavis
    login backend = mavis
    pap backend = mavis
    skip missing groups = yes
    host = world {
            address = 0.0.0/0
            #prompt = "Welcome\n"
            key = cisco
    }

    group = devops {
            default service = permit
            service = shell {
                    default command = permit
                    default attribute = permit
                    set priv-lvl = 15
            }
    }
```

}

what really did the trick is adding

```
setenv UNLIMIT_AD_GROUP_MEMBERSHIP = "1"
setenv AD_GROUP_PREFIX = ""
```

with these settings it's not looking for a prefix to the all the ad groups. This config allows for a direct mappings of ad group to the group configured in this file, in my case the group is called dev ops. also note that I had to use quotes around the 1. without these quests it does not set the var UNLIMIT_AD_GROUP_MEMBERSHIP to one so watch out for that. hopefully this can help someone else so they do not have to go through all the pain I did ;)